# Accessing UIViewcontroller from a subview - iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView .xib file. This is opened from the storyboard entry point UIViewController1 as a subview. The subview has a IBButton which when pressed opens a UIViewController2. Is this possible by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a segue going from your first view controller to your second. I'm going to name it `OpenViewController2`. We'll be able to call that segue programmatically.

In your `UIView` .h file, create a protocol that defines a delegate for that view:

SomethingView.h:

```
@protocol SomethingViewDelegate <NSObject> {
    - (void)importantThingHappened;
}

...

@interface SomethingView {
    id<SomethingViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<SomethingViewDelegate> delegate;
```

SomethingView.m:

```
@implementation
@synthesize delegate;

...

// The IBAction for the button in your view
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    [delegate importantThingHappened];
}
```

MyViewController.m, where you create your view:

```
// Create view
UIView *myView = ...

myView.delegate = self;
```

Later in MyViewController:

```
// Implement the protocol. This function will be called when the button action
// inside of the UIView you created is pressed
- (void)importantThingHappened {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OpenViewController2" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Is there any samples on creating segue? Is that a custom segue?

Answer (score 0):

First give your IBButton an unique tag, and in your UIViewController's viewDidLoad,

```
// add following line into viewDidLoad

[(UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:MY_UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_BUTTON] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and finally implement the buttonPressed: for whatever you want

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(UIButton*)aButton {
    // do what you want to do.
}
```

Comment: Im expecting to transit from one viewcontroller to another on pressing a button which is on UIView(subview). Is that possible?

Comment: This subview is an external .xib file